# Something wrong when using paint() in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

When I try to draw an oval in `JFrame`, the paint() method doesn't work, but when I change `JFrame` to `Frame` it's fine. Can you please explain this problem?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Window;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Oval extends JFrame
{
    public Oval()
    {
    //  this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawOval(40, 40, 40, 40);
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        new Oval();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't override `paint()`. Instead add a `JPanel` to the `JFrame` and override `paintComponent(g)`
2. Call `super` method. Even if you override `paint()` call `super.paint()` (Of course it's better to use `paintComponnet()`)

Answer (score 2):

Well you shouldn't override the `paint()` method, instead add a `JPanel` to your `JFrame` and override the `JPanel's` `paintComponent()` method and draw your stuff on the JPanel instead.

Here's a demonstration:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Oval extends JFrame
{
  public Oval()
  {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    OvalPanel ovalPanel = new OvalPanel(100); // SIZE of oval is 100
    ovalPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

    add(ovalPanel);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        new Oval();
      }
    });
  }
}

class OvalPanel extends JPanel
{
  private final int SIZE;

  public OvalPanel(final int size)
  {
    this.SIZE = size;
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g); // Call the super class's paintComponent so that it does its appropriate rendering first.
    g.drawOval((getWidth() - SIZE) >> 1, (getHeight() - SIZE) >> 1, SIZE, SIZE); // Center the oval
  }
}
```

Also if you notice, I used `SwingUtlities.invokeLater()` method and there I called the Oval constructor. That I did because Swing is thread unsafe and so you should call any Swing related methods in the Event Dispatcher Thread which is responsible for handling any Swing related stuff, and that's what the `invokeLater()` method does.

Note: if you're using JDK 8, you can write the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` statement as:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Oval::new); // That's JDK 8 Method reference feature.
```

You might wonder as to why you shouldn't do stuff directly in the `paint()` method. The reason has to do with the way `paint()` method is called. You see, the `RepaintManager` is responsible for handling the painting of all the Swing based components, and when the `paint()` method is called, it in turn calls the `paintComponent()`, `paintChildren()` and `paintBorder()` methods. `paintComponent()` is the best place to handle any component based rendering and that's why its the suggestion. Though, even the following code works:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Oval extends JFrame
{
  public Oval()
  {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paint(g); // Calling the super class's paint method first.
    // so that it handles its rendering.
    g.drawOval(40, 40, 40, 40);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new Oval();
  }
}
```

Even the order in which methods are called is important in Swing. Like:

```
setSize(400, 400); // Setting the size of JFrame first.
setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Locating the JFrame based on its size then.
setVisible(true); // Finally its made visible
```

All the above work as expected. But the following won't display the results properly:

```
setVisible(true); // JFrame is already made visible
setLocationRelativeTo(null); // This first locates the JFrame based on its (0, 0) size
setSize(400, 400); // Then its size is increased. Not as expected as the JFrame appears shifted from center.
```

Comment: a coupe of comments: a) unrelated: [don't use setXXSize, ever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657) - instead, override the getters to return sizing hints that are more appropriate than those calculated by default b) the implementation of paintComponent is violation the panel's contract to fill all its area with a fully opaque color

Comment: @kleopatra: I've updated my answer based on your comment, and hopefully they satisfy both your mentioned coding practices. Thanks.

Comment: +1, thanks! Though (nitpicking a bit :-): strictly speaking, your getXXSize implementations violate the method contract (in not returning a potentially previously set xx)

Comment: @kleopatra: Updated the answer now. I don't think that any nitpicking will work on it now. :D +1 for your answer in this [don't setXXSize, ever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi/7229519#7229519) link and thanks.

Comment: this.setVisible(true); 
    this.setSize(400, 400);
its work ok when i use frame instead of Jframe??

Comment: @user3429135: Well they'll work even with JFrame. Did you try the program snippet that I have written above?